# Prevent Grails Asset-Pipeline from changing File Name?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin

I use Grails 2.4.4 and the asset-pipeline plugin. One of my assets is a PDF file. I want that the name `someName.pdf` while remain when a user downloads this file. In my GSP I use it as:

```
<a href="${assetPath(src: 'someName.pdf', absolute:true)}" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

When I run in production the downloaded file name is:

```
someName-a9070ffc23b73b681ba027cbbe55b650.pdf
```

**How can I prevent the asset-pipeline plugin from changing the name of pdf files in production mode?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref https://github.com/bertramdev/grails-asset-pipeline/issues/229

> simply place the pdf file in the web-app folder instead of assets folder.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. It runs perfect in dev mode but in production the file could not be found. Is there anything missing here?

Comment: Well, I found this thread on github. https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/229. I think you are the one in the conversation? I guess you got the answer. Positng it here for everybody else. Cheers ;)

Comment: What was the solution for this?

 github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/229 is down :(